# Single countable word for trash/garbage

Tags: single-word-requests, uncountable-nouns

I am can't seem to think of a single word for trash or garbage in the singular form.

I want to use in a sentence like so:

> I picked up two [trashes] yesterday.

Obviously that is wrong because trash is uncountable. Which word can I use instead to have the same meaning as

> I picked up two [pieces of trash] yesterday.

In a nutshell I am looking for the direct translation of the french word "Déchet". Google comes up "Waste" but "2 Waste" doesn't sound right.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there is a "single word" in standard English that means "a unit of trash".

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks. Nothing springs to mind and "pieces of trash" is common. You could try "scraps". Does that work for you?

Comment: Only one word comes to my mind, a disposable. But disposables are things designed for one-time use and they are called disposables in any state: before use and after use. Still, it is a case when a disposable turns into a countable piece of garbage in the end.

Comment: Not a single word but you can consider *waste item*.

Comment: You're going to have to settle for "pieces of trash" or "pieces of litter" or "pieces of garbage" or "pieces of refuse"... in general it's ***pieces of*** *something*

Comment: As @ermanen said: "I picked up two **items of** trash yesterday." For mass nouns, it will be necessary to depend on another countable as a unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual garbage disposing action is picking bags or packs or containers with garbage. Consider these:

> I picked up two bags of waste yesterday.
>
> I picked up two packs of trash yesterday.

The only thing I know that can be a countable piece of trash is a disposable. Disposables are diapers, syringes, cartridges, etc.

Comment: A countable term for waste does not exist in many languages. There is no countable term in Russian either.

Comment: Perhaps, because nobody tries to count garbage unless it is packed in countable units :-)